# How do I get the menu that has flashing, speed, type and scale? (Picture below)

Tags: objects

I'm relatively new to Blender. My Blender version is 3.1.2. I was looking for a way to change the rotation speeds of objects, but I couldn't find anything.

Then, I came across this video on YT, but he hasn't left a tutorial.

Does someone know how to get that menu? Any help is welcome.

[image: Menu highlighted in red.]

Comment: As josh sanfelici says in his answer, those are custom properties, but a link to the YT video would be helpful anyway otherwise we'd just have to guess!

Answer (score 0):

Thoose kind of properties are not standard, they are called "custom properties", programmed by the artist who prepared the scene.

They are variables that can have any name and can be used to drive any other property, but you will not find them in any standard Blender object, you'll have to program them by yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the answer those are indeed programmed custom properties, in line to my question about "change rotation speed of objects" i did tweaked my graph editor and keyframes of objects to give it the animation i wanted.